# What is the relationship between generics and actual types ? (dart)

Tags: generics, flutter, dart

When defining base classes, I find that generics and actual types are somewhat different and confusing.

Like the following:

When I use basic types, the code works well.

```dart
void main() {
  var aa = AA.name("11");
  aa.test();
}

class AA<T> {
  T field;

  AA.name(this.field);

  void test() {
    print(field.runtimeType); 
    print(T); 
    print(field.runtimeType == T);  
  }
}
```

this result:

```
String
String
true
```

But when I use other types, things change.

```dart
void main() {
  var aa = AA.name(["11"]);
  aa.test();
}

class AA<T> {
  T field;

  AA.name(this.field);

  void test() {
    print(field.runtimeType);
    print(T);
    print(field.runtimeType == T);
  }
}
```

the result:

```
List<String>
List<String>
false
```

Both are List < String > types. Why are the corresponding types different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change this line

```
print(field.runtimeType == T);
```

to

```
print(field.runtimeType.toString() == T.toString());
```

It will return true.

Comment: I know "toString" is the same, but why are the two types different?

Comment: This is just my guess. I think filed.runtimeType return type is Type, T return type is different type. I couldn't not find exact document that i can show you. [Type of rutimeType](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.1/dart-core/Object/runtimeType.html)

Comment: Thank you. I found that this problem only exists in `List`:

```dart
void main() {
  var aa = AA.name(BB<num>());
  aa.test();
}

class AA<T> {
  T field;

  AA.name(this.field);

  void test() {
    print(field.runtimeType); // BB<num>
    print(T); //  BB<num>
    print(field.runtimeType == T); // true
  }
}

class BB<T> {}
```

I think maybe `List` has some special features.